# If WebForm would be worthless disable ViewState?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I'm a new comer to ASP.NET. Before that, I was a classic ASPer.

As I know:

1. ViewState use to maintain some complicate-property(sorry for my arbitrary description.Only to differentiate basic property like value).
2. ViewState go with PostData and back to server in PostBackData.
3. ViewState record the latest control status. Compare it with PostData to determine if a event should be fire like SelectedIndexChange.

WebForm is Event base and disable ViewState this engine failed. But ViewState could be mighty.

On some well-known Asp.Net sites like

https://stackoverflow.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/

when I look over source code.I can't see something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="31zA00LgYW9+3QuC4YmxF4w3eBAWhuZRL89OB+6X4AwCFpYIR2914D5a4PWubGveAods0+i/2T21mmpYlHx/sv+5gsGfyYPd0bhj76B0yy4=" />
```

Does those websites never use a runat="Server" and disable ViewState?

If so, I don't Know the reason to use WebForm when throw away ViewState. Why not MVC?

Comment: Check http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: SO use MVC. But [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) definitely use WebForm. And you can't see ViewState on [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1649/Csharp.aspx) . As its .aspx suffix, I think there is no run at server control on the page. So my question still persistence "what the meaning use WebForm when throw away ViewState?"
 
However, thanks Murali comment. SO, sorry for misunderstand.